# Skobbler Map: reverse geocodder returning NULL for some attibutes in SKSearchResult

Tags: android, reverse-geocoding, skmaps, skobbler-maps

Under SKSearchResult object, the parameters street, house number, neighbourhood, zip code, state code, region, citySector, state, and poi always contains NULL in result. Any solutions? Thanks..

```
if(mapView!=null) {
        SKSearchResult result = SKReverseGeocoderManager.getInstance().reverseGeocodePosition(mapView.getMapCenter());
        if (result != null) {
            String address = "";
            Log.d("Test", " result " + result.getAddress());
            address+=result.getName()+"\n";

            //address+=result.getAddress();

            if(result.getAddress().getStreet()  != null)
                address+=" "+result.getAddress().getStreet();//here return null
            if(result.getAddress().getHouseNumber()  != null)
                address+=" "+result.getAddress().getHouseNumber();//here return null
            btnAddress.setText(address);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this with the latest version of the SDK? 3.0.0?

Comment: @Ando I have the same problem and I am using SDK 3.0.1